# How to change the size of R plots in Jupyter?

Tags: r, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am wondering how to configure Jupyter to plot a smaller figure within R kernel.

I have tried using `options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75, repr.plot.res = 300)`, but the result is kinda messy. It is changing the size of the plot R produced. Are there any ways I can directly configure the output graph size in Jupyter.

In other words, how can I change the size in the first figure to the size in the second figure, while not messing up the plot.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 13):

You should simply change the resolution of your plot. For instance, try `repr.plot.res = 100` in:

```
options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75, repr.plot.res = 100)
```

Comment: Using this on Colab is giving the error `invalid graphics state`, which it can't recover from with `dev.off()` and I have to restart the runtime.

Comment: @EduardoReis: I'm also getting this error. It says: `Error in value[[3L]](cond): invalid graphics state
Traceback:
plot without title`

Comment: @Leonidas Avoid setting of `width` or `height` as 1. I don't see the `plot without title` error  when using `~1.85` or above.

Answer (score 11):

You need to manually set the tick size, marker size and text size. The text size and tick size can be set through the `theme()` function, while marker size through `geom_point()` function.

```
df_1 = data.frame(x=c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9), y = c(200, 225, 250, 270, 310))

options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75)
ggplot(df_1, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(size = 0.3) + 
   theme(text = element_text(size = 3), element_line(size = 0.1))
```

[image]