# Rmarkdown: resizing charts in PowerPoint output

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, powerpoint, pandoc

While automating data reports with Rmarkdown I have been facing a challenge that I could not overcome yet: resizing bar charts produced with `ggplot2` for the bars to be exactly the same width across charts.
Let's say I am creating a bar chart with 4 horizontal bars. In the PowerPoint output, each bar has a width `W`, and the figure has size `totalW`, `totalH`.
In the next slide, I'm creating another bar chart with 6 horizontal bars, how can I make sure that the bars in the second chart have the same width `W` as in the first chart, and that the figure size is `totalW`, `6/4 * totalH`?

I have tried several approaches, mostly from [here](https://sebastiansauer.github.io/figure_sizing_knitr/) and [here](https://www.zevross.com/blog/2017/06/19/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-images-and-figures-in-r-markdown-documents/):

1. resizing charts with the `options` function from `repr` library, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729049/how-to-change-the-size-of-r-plots-in-jupyter) for outputs in Jupyter;
2. setting `out.width` and `out.height` for each chart in the respective code chunk;
3. setting `fig.width` and `fig.height` for each chart in the respective code chunk;
4. setting figure size while exporting with `ggsave` and setting the rendering size with `pandoc` syntax.

While the first two approaches have no effect in PowerPoint outputs, the last two have exactly the same output: figures of different sizes, both in width and height, and messed up font sizes (as expectable from `fig.width` and `fig.height`).

Below a reproducible example of each approach, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZCkYwTSCUh4s7H2XM3bq3ZxrFbsgTEWE/view?usp=sharing) the `*.Rmd` file.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


# generate data
set.seed(123) 
df <- data.frame(id = seq(1, 21, by = 1),
                 category = c(rep("catX", 9), rep("catY", 12)),
                 type = c(rep("t1", 3), rep("t2", 3), rep("t3", 3), rep("t4", 3), 
                                 rep("t5", 3), rep("t6", 3), rep("t7", 3)),
                 level = sample(c(rep("high", 5), rep("medium", 7), rep("low", 9))))

dfX <- df %>% filter(category == "catX")
dfY <- df %>% filter(category == "catY")

# create function
mk_chart <- function(df, t="type", l="level", horizontal=TRUE) {
    p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(.data[[t]]),
                        fill = .data[[l]])) +
        geom_bar(position = "fill", width = 0.45) +
        theme(legend.position = "bottom")
    if (horizontal) {
        p <- p + coord_flip()
    }
    return(p)
}
```

Approach 1

```r
options(repr.plot.width = 14, repr.plot.height = 8)
p1 <- mk_chart(dfX)
p1
```

---

```r
options(repr.plot.width = 14, repr.plot.height = 12)
p2 <- mk_chart(dfY)
p2
```

Approach 2:

```r
# {r out.width='14in', out.height='8in'} in first code chunk

p1 <- mk_chart(dfX)
p1
```

---

```r
# {r out.width='14in', out.height='12in'} in second code chunck

p2 <- mk_chart(dfY)
p2
```

Approach 3:

```r
# {r, fig.width=14, fig.height=8}

p1 <- mk_chart(dfX)
p1
```

---

```r
# {r, fig.width=14, fig.height=12}

p2 <- mk_chart(dfY)
p2
```

Approach 4:
*Please note that this generates `*.png` files on your local machine. Do not run if you are not comfortable with that.*

```r
p1 <- mk_chart(dfX)
ggsave(p1, 
       filename = "plot1.png",
       width = 14,
       height = 8,
       units = "in")
```

`![](./plot1.png){width=14in, height=8in}`

---

```r
p2 <- mk_chart(dfY)
ggsave(p2, 
       filename = "plot2.png",
       width = 14,
       height = 12,
       units = "in")
```

`![](./plot2.png){width=14in, height=12in}`

I am aware that this is a rather special case as (almost) nobody cares of having bars of exactly same size, but my interest is understanding the possible solutions to resize charts/maps/figures in PowerPoint outputs using Rmarkdown or any other relevant syntax. Any hint on that regard is highly appreciated.