# How to reduce the size of a plot in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: r, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying out R with Jupyter Notebook and for some reason the plots are huge. How can I reduce the size of the plot? I tried changing the `plot_scale` option via: `options(jupyter.plot_scale=.25`) but nothing happened. I've tried other numbers besides .25, but it has no effect.

I also tried
`options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75, repr.plot.res = 100)`
as well as `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = c("text/plain", "image/png" ))`, but both gave the following error:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond): invalid graphics state
Traceback:


plot without title
```

Ideally, I'm looking for a global solution (i.e. one that changes the default plot size, rather than having to individually scale each plot). Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: See [How to change the size of R plots in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42729049/8508004). Unless the syntax has changed recently , I think you are looking for `repr.plot`-related attributes.

Comment: There's also `options(jupyter.plot_mimetypes = c("text/plain", "image/png" ))` . See [here](https://notebook.community/andrie/jupyter-notebook-samples/Changing%20R%20plot%20options%20in%20Jupyter) and [here](http://compbio.ucsd.edu/outputting-beautiful-jupyter-notebooks-r-kernel-edition/).

Comment: @Wayne: Thanks for your comment. I read that post and tried the following that was suggested: `options(repr.plot.width = 1, repr.plot.height = 0.75, repr.plot.res = 100)`. Unfortunately, I got the following error: `Error in value[[3L]](cond): invalid graphics state Traceback: plot without title`.  The `options` code you suggested produced exactly the same error...anything else I should try?

Comment: Use ggplot? Compare in your notebook: `library(ggplot2);options(repr.plot.width = 15, repr.plot.height =15);ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 6)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=sin)
` vs `library(ggplot2);options(repr.plot.width = 4, repr.plot.height =4);ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0, 6)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=sin)`

Comment: By the way, `options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5);x = seq(0,2*pi, length = 50);y = sin(x);plot(x,y)` vs `options(repr.plot.width = 15, repr.plot.height = 15);x = seq(0,2*pi, length = 50);y = sin(x);plot(x,y)` does work, too. It's just if you set width and height at 1 you get that `plot without title` error.

Comment: And it does seem if you put `options(repr.plot.width = 7, repr.plot.height = 7)` towards the top of your notebook, it does affect the plots that are run after. Meaning you don't have to necessarily put it in the code for each individual plot.

Comment: Aside from my answer I would suggest you to use Rstudio and dump Jupyter when using R.. its very refined and has good features like syntax highlighting, publishing Rshiny apps, Rmarkdown, easy acces to documentation of functions and libraries etc.

Comment: @Wayne: Thank you, it worked!!! There were two problems I encountered when I first tried your answer: First, I set `rep.plot.width` and `rep.plot.height` too small, causing the `plot without title` error, as you pointed. Secondly, I had tested this with multiple plots, i.e. using `par(mfrow = c(3,2))` without realizing that `rep.plot.width` and `rep.plot.height` refer to the width and height of the *entire* plot, not each individual subplots.

Comment: @Wayne: If you want to post an answer, I'll give you +150! 

Also, I have one follow-up question: I created two sets of six subplots using `par(mfrow = c(3,2))`, using different numbers for each set of plots.  The sizes of each set of plots are how I want them, thanks to your solution. However, Jupyter creates a scroll bar for one set of plots, but not the other. I would prefer not to have a scroll bar. Is there a setting where I can disable the scrolling? Or change the minimum dimensions for when the scroll bar kicks in? Thanks again!

Comment: @Wayne: Also, I forgot to mention that I'm using base R, not ggplot...

Comment: @Wayne: I just found the answer to my question: `Cell --> All Ouput --> Toggle Scrolling`. No more scroll bar now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
options(repr.plot.width = 5, repr.plot.height = 5)
x = seq(0,2*pi, length = 50)
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y)
```

Then compare it to the output from the following in another cell or after restarting the kernel:

```
options(repr.plot.width = 15, repr.plot.height = 15)
x = seq(0,2*pi, length = 50)
y = sin(x)
plot(x,y)
```

You should see a difference.

If you set the width and height to you get `plot without title` error.
Should be good with 2 or above because ~1.8 or above worked in my tests.

Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42729049/8508004).

Answer (score 0):

**simply** run

```
dev.off()
```

**then rerun** your code for plotting.

Alternativly use ggplot. If the error persists you should still try dev.off() and rerun your code.

Otherwise you still have the option to restart your notebook or reinstall R.